# Continuous implies surjective

Tags: calculus

Suppose $g(x)$ is a function from the set of non negative reals to the set of non negative reals such that $g(x)=x^3+cx$ where $c$ is a constant.Does there exist an $a$ such that $a^3+ca=1$?
I tried proving that using Intermediate Value theorem but can't actually prove.

Comment: Since $c \geq 0$ [can you see why?], you have $g(0) = 0 < 1 \leq 1+c = g(1)$...

Comment: Your title is somewhat unrelated to your question -- certainly $g$ is continuous (and it will be surjective), but in general continuous functions need not be surjective!

Answer (score 1):

Continuity in general does not imply surjectivity. In this case, we are closer to the following situation: suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ is continuous and is such that $f(0) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$. Then $f$ is surjective.

To prove this, let $a \geq 0$ be given. Since $f \to \infty$ we can choose $x$ with $f(x) > a$. Then since $f$ is continuous we have by the intermediate value theorem that $f$ attains all values in the range $[f(0), f(x)] = [0, f(x)]$. But $a \in [0, f(x)]$ since $0 \leq a < f(x)$. Thus $a$ is in the image of $f$. This shows $f$ is surjective.

For your specific function, it is easy to verify the hypotheses.

Answer (score 0):

So we have $x^3 +cx < 0$ for all $x < 0$.  So $cx < -x^3$ and $c > -x^2$ for all $x<0$ so $c\ge 0$.

So $0^3 + 0\cdot c = 0 < 1$ and $1^3 + 1\cdot c \ge 1$ so by Intermediate Value Theorem there is an $a: 0 < a \le 1$ where $a^3 + ac = 1$.

What does your *title* have to do with anything though.